# Can't access local SMB share via DNS name on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, file-sharing, windows-server-2008-r2, smb

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with single network adapter. For this adapter I created two IP addresses and registered DNS aliases for each one:
1.2.3.4 => app1.rnd.example.com
1.2.3.5 => app2.rnd.example.com

The server itself is included in domain as srv1.lab.example.com (i.e. domain is lab.example.com).

Then I created a shared folder with Read/Write permissions to Everyone.

I can access both shares via IP addresses. I can access both shares via DNS-aliases from outside of the server.
But when I try to access shares via DNS-aliases (\\app1.rnd.example.com\myshare) from inside of the server then I'm prompted for credentials.

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried it by turning off the firewall? Where did you register the DNS addresses (domain DNS?), and what type of environment are you in? Is the server on a domain? How are you logging in? To a domain or to your local computer?

Comment: @KCotreau, I've updated the Q with details.

Comment: What are the server's DNS entries, same server or a different one? If on the same server are they set to the IP (recommended by Microsoft), or to the loopback (127.0.0.1)? Can you browse to the share and does it still request credentials? I have to say, this is a strange one.

Comment: @KCotreau, sorry, but I don't fully understand what do you mean by "server's DNS entries: same server or a different one". I asked our administrators to create DNS names for particular IP-addresses (one-to-one).

DNS entites are made not on the server itself, but somewhere in domain. So they should point to the IP. I can check this by "nslookup" tool:
"nslookup app1.example.com" return "1.2.3.4".

Comment: Same server, network properties>the LAN connection>TCP/IP properties, what are the settings for the DNS server? Is the DNS server on the same server we are talking about or on another one?

Comment: Ah, DNS server is on another one

Comment: To be honest, without seeing it, I have to say I am stumped. It is so strange that you can do it using the IP, but not with the sharename. I am sorry, but I am at a bit of a loss.